# Contact Update from Authenticated Site User

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, crud

I have an existing Apex class that serves as a controller in a force.com site visualforce page. The Apex class is performing an update on the Contact sObject directly and I believe the update should fail based on the fact that users who are logged in have the [Authenticated Site](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_platformportal.htm&type=5) user license.

That license does not allow any CRUD on the Contact object, yet the update works. I added some proofs in the apex to show the issue, can anyone explain why this works?

```
System.debug('sObjectType is : ' + theContact.Id.getSobjectType() ); //Prints "sObjectType is : Contact"

System.debug('Contact can be updated : ' + Schema.sObjectType.Contact.isUpdateable() );//Prints "Contact can be updated : false"

Database.SaveResult sr = System.Database.update(theContact, true);

System.debug('Update on Contact worked : ' + sr.isSuccess() );//Prints "Update on Contact worked : true"
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are your Authenticated Website users logging in to a Customer Portal or to a Customer Community?  When you look at the Site in Setup > Develop > Sites, is it a standard site or is it marked for a Community?

Comment: @DavidCheng it is enabled for a Customer Portal.

Comment: I don't understand why the users need to go to the Site.  Since they're already logged in through portal, why not just set up a custom tab for your  Visualforce page so they can access it from their tab row?  Sites are generally intended for unauthenticated public users, and the built-in Guest User for a site does have read/create permissions available for Contact.  Have you checked the Site's public access settings?

Comment: @DavidCheng, The solution involves a custom skin for the portal.  The UI is entirely Visualforce with Apex used in controllers to access the underlying data.  The user license for the portal doesn't allow crud on the contact object but somehow this code is doing it.  Despite the fact that the apex class returns false for Schema.sObjectType.Contact.isUpdateable();